# Login with Google doesn't work inside LikedIn mobile app's internal browser/webview

Tags: webview, linkedin-api, google-signin

I have a web application that offers users the option to Login with Google. This feature works OK when users use a regular browser, but when they use the LinkedIn mobile app's internal browser, it doesn't. In this case, I see Error 403: disallowed_useragent.

[image]

I can see this error is happening not only for us, but for a bunch of other companies. To reproduce it you can just navigate to the page of any company/application that offers Login with Google and hit the company link in the "About" section. Examples: Figma, Full Story, Evernote, Udemy, etc.

This issue is related to [some changes Google did recently that disallows OAuth requests from embedded views](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/upcoming-security-changes-to-googles-oauth-2.0-authorization-endpoint.html), and as far as I understand it should be fixed on LinkedIn's side. But anyway, is there anything I can do on my end to prevent this error?

Answer (score 0):

If it was your own app that was causing the issue, then I would recommend the same solution as the [article that you posted](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/upcoming-security-changes-to-googles-oauth-2.0-authorization-endpoint.html)

> Apps should allow general, third-party links to be handled by the default behaviors of the operating system, enabling a user's preferred routing to their chosen default web browser or another developer's preferred routing

However, there's nothing you can do about the behavior of your site through LinkedIn's embedded WebView other than asking users to open the login using their system browser. If LinkedIn has fixed the issue as you say, you could try updating the app if it's not up to its latest. Another option you could explore is not displaying the 'Login with Google' option to [specific user-agents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent), but this is probably a bad idea as the article points out.

For a full fix, you're just going to have to wait for LinkedIn to fix their app, or use a different OAuth provider.